Advice on learning interest rates and options trading
Would you have some advice for someone to learn sell side interest rates and options trading on their own? I have looked at so many books, but the focus is so much on valuation and the mathematics and very little about real market intuition. Any help?

You should read  J Hamish M Darbyshire Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives: A Practical Guide to Swaps
